# What is this (presumably Catholic) uniform?

Tags: catholicism, clothing, vestments

Yesterday, at a restaurant in Rome, at the table next to mine, there were seated four people: a Catholic priest (in a kind of cassock), two lay people, and the woman in the photo, who apparently wears some kind of religious uniform (as well as a crucifix on a chain) that I couldn't recognise.

[image]

Does anyone know which uniform is this?

Comment: It looks like a Camillians novice or some similar order that takes care of sick or poor.

Comment: What, that isn't what the pizza chefs in Rome are wearing these days?

Comment: Never seen a religious habit with short sleeves. Could be wrong, but this looks like a student studying in a private Catholic School, wearing a school uniform. Most religious do not go out for lunch or dinner. Diocesan priests do all the time! Female religious do not ware earrings.

Answer (score 2):

She could be of the Order of the Camillians, who takes care of the sick and dying, or she could simply be an altar server after a matyr celebration or Palm Sunday (the red belt).